# Unable to store data to Firebase using React Native and Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm facing an issue while trying to store data in Firebase Firestore from a React Native app. I have a config.js file for Firebase configuration and an app.js file for the main logic.

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyAFS0Hmyle5jRaPq-t3tEHnyPbIZRob4t0",
authDomain: "student-ec994.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://student-ec994-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "student-ec994",
storageBucket: "student-ec994.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "430360101900",
appId: "1:430360101900:web:c4bb2208f87ba731099a29"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const database = getFirestore(app);

export default database;
```

And here's my app.js:

```
import database from './config';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Pressable, Text, View, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';
import { addDoc, collection } from 'firebase/firestore';

export default function App() {
 const [sroll, setRoll] = useState('');
 const [sname, setName] = useState('');
 const [sclass, setClass] = useState('');
 const value = collection(database, "demo");

 const handleAdd = async () => {
   console.log('Before addDoc');
   await addDoc(value, { name: sname, roll: sroll, class: sclass });
   console.log('After addDoc');
 };

 // ... rest of your component logic
}
```

I've added debug statements, and I noticed that only the "Before addDoc" log is being printed, and the "After addDoc" log is not. I'm not sure why the data is not being stored. Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ignoring potential errors. Catch the error and log the result to determine what's going wrong:

```
const handleAdd = async () => {
  console.log('Before addDoc');
  try {
    await addDoc(value, { name: sname, roll: sroll, class: sclass });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
  console.log('After addDoc');
};
```